# React warning on setState when unmounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

When I execute the following code (see snippet below), I get the warning:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Blinker component.

Is there something I am doing wrong in my componentWillUnmount() method under my Mounter class? Thanks!

```js
class Blinker extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appear: true
    }
    this.blinker = this.blinker.bind(this);
  }

  blinker()  {
    this.setState({appear: !this.state.appear });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.blinker, 300)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { (this.state.appear) && "xxx" }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Mounter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      render: true
    };
    this.interval = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setTimeout( () =>
      this.rendering(), 1500
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  rendering() {
    this.setState({ render: !this.state.render });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          { this.state.render && <Blinker /> }
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }   
}



ReactDOM.render(<Mounter />, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't throw a warning. i'm not sure this is related but you call `clearInterval` on a `setTimeout` function. did you mean to call `clearTimeout` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear `this.interval` and check it before setting state.  This will guard against setting state when your component has been unmounted.

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
  this.interval = null; // clear
}

rendering() {
  // this.interval will be null when unmounting so avoid setting state:
  if (this.interval) {
    this.setState({
      render: !this.state.render
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Timer methods can be tricky because they might trigger before `componentWillUnmount` trigger but the state setting can happen after component unmounted because `setState` is async. To deal with this you can use [react-timer-mixin](https://github.com/reactjs/react-timer-mixin#react-timer-mixin).

> ### react-timer-mixin
>
> Using bare setTimeout, setInterval, setImmediate and
>   requestAnimationFrame calls is very dangerous because if you forget to
>   cancel the request before the component is unmounted, you risk the
>   callback throwing an exception.
>
> If you include TimerMixin, then you can replace your calls to
>   `setTimeout(fn, 500)` with `this.setTimeout(fn, 500)` (just prepend
>   `this`.) and everything will be properly cleaned up for you.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary in this case to add a dependency to your application.  Checking for the saved interval ID is adequate and smaller in code size.

Comment: @Scott thank you for your input but it is a react suggested way of handling timers so I thought I should suggest that. Although your solution is good for most of the time there is still a small chance of getting warning since `setState` can finish anytime in the future as the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) states. Component can be un-mounted after the if statement and before the setState call.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded so it is not possible for the component to be un-mounted after the if statement and before the setState call.